# PIE Etymology of Ger *heute* "today" vs Lt *hodie*, Sanskr *adja* etc

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

This question about [Top of the morning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51427/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-top-of-the-morning-to-you) got me thinking.

Most west european words for *today* are akin, said to be influenced by Latin *hodie*<sup>1</sup>. But Sanskrit *adja*, from * PIE *h₁e-dy-és, *h₁é (“this”, and then) + "day", follows the same scheme, and *h₁é "this, and then", *ḱe- "this", does not seem to make much of a difference.

That disconnect alone would warrant a question. It does seem to be a proper Proto-Indo-European term, perhaps with dialectal differences. What's the problem between *ḱ and *h₁, isn't this just evidence that a voiceless palatal stop and that laryngeal, that could be anywhere between a glottal stop [ʔ] and "an h sound [h]" (e.g. a voiceless glottal fricative), were, for lack of a better word, pretty close, not to say rather variable (I mean a stop is in principle not phonetic, so the phonemic realization might vary easily, unless it's contrasting)?

Bonus points if "ahoy-hoy" belongs here.

<sub>1.</sub>

- Ger *heute*, OE *hēodæġ*, from PGmc *hiz "this" + *dagaz* "day", *hiz from PIE *ḱe; The Nordic *i dag* variants probably belong here to, I presume.
- Welsh *heddiw* from PCelt *so-~se- "this" + "day" (surely from PIE *ḱe?);
- Ru *сего́дня* (sevodnja), from PSlav *sь "this" + *dьnь "day", *sь from PIE *ḱe;
- Agr σήμερον (sḗmeron), first part from PIE *ḱe
- Fr *hui* Sp *huy* from Vulgar Latin *oie, from Latin *hodie*, *hoc* "this" + *die* "day", *hoc* from PIE *ḱe.
  y

Comment: Aren't most of these words formed in historical times? We know when Latin "hoc+die=hodie" appeared, and English "to+day=today" is centuries later, and Norwegian "i+dag=idag" not until the late 19th century (and it was rejected as a word in 1938 reforms). Sure, maybe the English and Norwegian were influenced by the preposition+day Latin structure, while the German went with this instead of a preposition under the influence of the Latin sounds, or something like that, but whether that's true or not, surely they didn't inherit a word from PIE.

Comment: I suspect that forming "today" as a contraction of either "to+day" or "this+day" is just the kind of obvious thing that many languages will independent hit on. Japanese "honjitsu" is pretty similar, but presumably it was either borrowed from Chinese or invented in Japanese, not inherited from PIE, right? And meanwhile, if every IE language contracted this+day completely independently, they'd still mostly look pretty similar because they mostly have related words for this and day.

Comment: @abarnert disregard the Norwegian then. The basic question is why the Latin would be significant for German. It certainly may have helped to reinforce the idea, sure, but if it's such an obvious construction that supposedly existed in PIE already, why assume a a disconnect?

Comment: It's _not_ a construction that existed in PIE already; that's the point, that's why German had to construct it independently. And there are plenty of reasons why Latin would be significant for German. But the details are too much to get into in comments, so I'm writing an answer.

Comment: By the way, for your bonus points: ahoy-hoy < (modern English nautical jargon) ahoy < (Dutch) gooi < (Middle Dutch) goyen, which seems to be etymologically uncertain, but is clearly unrelated to anything having to do "dagaz", or anything else meaning "day" (or "this"/"here", or the prepositions used in Dutch, English, or any other languages instead). I see from searching around a bit that someone has argued that "ahoy" actually comes from German "Heu", which happens to sound like the first syllable of "heute", but is etymologically unrelated.

Comment: Old Dutch is tricky, badly attested. Accepting *gooi*, seeing it akin to *gay*, a source deriving \*ganhuz "sudden, quick" from PIE \*ǵʰengʰ- "walk, step", \*ǵʰēy- "go", that looks akin to *go* \*ǵʰeh₁- "to leave", I tentatively compare \*mey- "move", so Low German "moin" might be akin, which is also uncertain, but may relate to "bright, shiny" or "morning", or both. Thus, compare \*ǵʰelh₃- "yellow, shine". Compare analogous *kw>p, *gw>b, thus perhaps *gh>?>m. Compare *mellow* (\*mer(w) vs \*gʰer- "to rub"; Ger *gerben* \*ga+arwaz), *May* (*Maia* vs *Gaia*?), *mega* vs *giga*.

Comment: Yes, Old Dutch is badly attested, but what is the point of the rest of your comment? I don't know why you skipped the Middle Dutch, and I don't know how good your speculative alternative derivation is, but why would it matter to your question?

Comment: Also, it looks like most theories about "moin" involve borrowing, although nobody's sure who from—maybe a dead eastern Frisian language, maybe Prussian or another Baltic language, maybe an otherwise-unattested west Slavic language… So, even if you can somehow connect "gooi" to "moin", that really wouldn't help much (unless you want to argue that they're both borrowed from a Frisian root that you think you can derive or something).

Comment: @abarnert I meant old Dutch, not Old Dutch! All this hardly matters for the question, except for all the allusions to *shiny* etc. and for the *morgen, moryen* "(good) morning" derivation mentioned in Wiktionary. With *Morgen* "to-morrow" it might still be relevant for *Heute* "today". But I don't clearly see how.

Comment: A point in favor of Latin influence would be the names of week days. However, a comparison with Hindi and Greek to rule out older influences appears difficult (at least because Hindi itself isn't older). I'm tripped up by सप्ताह के दिन (saptāh ke din) "days of the week", due to *ke*, which is uncertain. शनिवार (śanivār) "saturday" reminds of Ger. *Sonnabend* "saturday; sun+evening". Then again Hi *saptah* reminds of Σάββατο (savvato) "sunday", Agr σάββατον "Sabbath". With "evening" in mind, read "week-end" instead. The seven-day week is Babylonian, I hear, and *seven* "7" has Semitic cognates.

Comment: We know Latin influenced German because there are hundreds of loanwords, because the borrowing process exhibits regularities, because they were obvious historical connections to explain the borrowing (like the Carolingians using Latin as the imperial language), etc. A single word (or group of five of them) that seems kind of more similar to Latin than to Hindi adds next to nothing, and the fact that one of the syllables in one of them is one you happened to already have in your head adds even less.

Comment: More generally, I'm getting the feeling that you don't understand the basic principles of how this works. To posit a genetic relationship, you can't just find two syllables that sound kind of similar in words with kind of related meanings. You need to establish a derivation that follows regular rules that match hundreds of other derivations. What you're doing is more akin to Greenberg-style mass comparison—but even more useless, because it's without the "mass" part.

Comment: You're also starting off with a hypothesis that you want to believe, and then trying to cherry-pick data to prove it, instead of gathering data and then trying to come up with a hypothesis that explains it. That isn't good science in _any_ field; the fact that historical linguistics is softer than physics doesn't change that.

Comment: I meant the influence with regards to speaking about days. I know that Latin influenced German on account of all the theology, if nothing else, for sure. Indeed I have little understanding of the conquest of the world. I had hoped with a nudge in a certain direction, I could bypass the tedious work and receive a positive answer, however the responses are becoming increasingly negative. You might opt to call *mess comparison* instead, because without reliance of highly regular sound shifts that have to happen mostly in isolation, the real picture is just that, messy.

Answer (score 4):

There's no evidence that "today" is a PIE term, and plenty of evidence that it isn't. For example:

- Different IE languages have contracted different roots to make their "today" words. That's already enough to rule out common descent.

  - In fact, the roots often don't even all have the same semantics: about half of them are "this+day" like German, about half are "preposition+day" like English, and maybe a few oddballs here and there. The ones that use prepositions often use different ones, like English "to+day" vs. Dutch "from+day" vs. Danish "in/on+day".
  - And these differences are clearly not at all distributed based on descent; Sanskrit and German are certainly not more closely related than German and Low German.
- These contractions appear long after the languages had diverged, which again is usually enough on its own to rule out common descent.<sup>2, 3</sup>
- Many non-IE languages have constructions that are semantically just as close as to "today" and "heute" as they are to each other, like Japanese "honjitsu" and Arabic al-yawma.

---

So, if they're independent coinages, why do some of them look so similar?

Well, it looks (see Arabic, Japanese, etc.) like forming "today" as a contraction is the kind of obvious thing that many languages will hit on once the host culture reaches a point where it needs a word like that.

There are only so many things you can plausibly contract to get "today": "to+day", "on+day", "this+day"… And if two different IE languages both contract their words for "this+day", those words are often going to be cognates, so the result will often look similar.

But again, notice that many of them are *not* cognates, and it seems to be almost random which ones are. Which is exactly what you'd expect from different IE languages developing their words independently, but out of a small and mostly-shared pool of inputs.

---

So, what do etymologists mean when they say OHG "hiutu" is a contraction of "hiu+tagu" *possibly influenced by Latin hodie*?

First, you asked in the comments why Latin would affect German in the first place. That's easy. When people were speaking OHG, Latin was the language of their religion, diplomacy, civil administration, and (if you include vulgar Latin) much of their trade. Almost any OHG speaker who was literate was literate in Latin. And Latin influence on Germanic languages even goes back long before that—the Romans were hiring Germans as mercenaries, resettling them all over Europe, and converting them to Christianity centuries before Charlemagne.

Also, notice that some of the Germanic languages ended up with a direct calque of the Latin contraction, but others are "phonocalques"—contractions that stretch the Latin semantics a bit further, but sounds a lot more like the Latin, especially with "heute". That *could* be a coincidence, but it certainly makes influence look even more plausible. I don't know exactly how compelling that argument is, but remember, the etymological dictionaries only say "possibly influenced".

---

<sub>1. Some as late as modern times—Norwegian rejected "idag" as an invalid new coinage in the 1938 reforms. Obviously the Latin and Greek aren't *that* new, but they appeared well after the start of historical writing, which is still millenia after the breakup of PIE.</sub>

<sub>2. Also, some languages coined the same idea multiple times. Low German "vandage" ("from+day") replaced "hiudu" ("this+day") in historical times. (Earlier, "hiudu" apparently replaced "hi(u)digu", which is formed from the same roots, but contracted differently. But it seems plausible to me that "hiudu" could be a borrowing from OHG "hiutu" rather than a re-coinage, so let's ignore it.)</sub>

Comment: Where are you getting "day+now" for Greek? σήμερον / τήμερον is "this day", from deictic *ki- plus ἡμέρα "day" (with a change of gender).

Comment: @TKR I don't know Greek, but the source I got that from says σήμερα is from Ancient Greek for "day", with the ending from τώρα "now". Checking a couple other sources, it looks like the Ancient Greek in question is σήμερον, which comes from kyāmeron, which does indeed mean "here + day" or "this + day", so the modern is more "today+now", or even "today, slightly modified by now", not "day+now". But I don't see how it changes the point.

Comment: @abarnert AGr *emar* "day" does in my Humble opinion look a bit like Semitic \*ywm (arab *al-yawam*, hebr *hayom*) but what do I know. 今天 and 今日 derive  *day* likewise from a sense *sky, sun* and eventually god. Note how today we write the day of Tyr, like every given tuesday. *honjitsu* derives from a sense "blade of grass" in one reading and "book" in another (*moto* and *hon*). Note that leaves are commonly used for writing (and grass blades surely allude to tally mark counting strokes, too). "*First, you asked in the comments why Latin would affect German in the first place*" no, I didn't.

Comment: "*Different IE languages have contracted different roots to make their "today" words. That's already enough to rule out common descent*". I remain unconvinced by your remark. They all reflect \*ke and I'm not sure that was still productive everywhere (if not, but fossilized, that would be it); The difference between \*deyw- and \*dhegwh- is, admittedly somerhing I overlooked whhen writing the question, but I think there's good reason not to addopt the stance that language began only with the youngest layer of PIE reconstructions.

Comment: @vectory I don't understand what your point is with most of the first comment. What does a Greek word looking a bit like a Semitic word have to do with whether the Greek word for "today" was inherited from PIE? What does the etymology of Japanese "day" have to do with the fact that it was later (after it already meant "day") used in a compound meaning "today"? And so on.

Comment: @vectory As for the non-sequitur at the end of the first comment: Yes, you did. In [this comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30229/#comment64925_30229): "The basic question is why the Latin would be significant for German".

Comment: @vectory Finally, for the important part: They do _not_ all reflect *ke. English to, Dutch van, and Danish i trace back to PIE *doh, *apo, and *hen, all completely unrelated to *ke. Even Latin hoc isn't *ke, it's *ghi + *ke. This is why I've ignored your attempt to somehow merge *h₁é and *ke and somehow even *so into the same morpheme: because even granting that, it still doesn't make most of the IE words cognate, so you still have to explain English, Dutch, Danish, Armenian, etc. And why some of the languages that _do_ have *ke have it as the suffix rather than the prefix. Etc.

Comment: "*These contractions appear long after the languages had diverged*" That's the most important point, not a by-the-way. I have no dating on any of this but the fact remains that Sanskrit supposedly reflects a PIE form as seen over at [wikt](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=अद्य&diff=48996564&oldid=48992244). I'm sure the editor would not draw further conclusions from that, but the question remains, why?

Comment: @vectory It's not a "by-the-way", it's one of the three pieces of evidence.

Comment: You are by the way missing completely to account for the fact that *this day* is somewhat unlikely to appear in writing intended to be read on many different days. I'm not sure that's to stand against the late appearance or with it. Bit you cannot just pick that it's a  naturally obvious construction depending on whether it fits your argument or not. That is, if it's rather recent and other prepositions liable to be used, I'd wonder what was used before, and whether that can't be chalked up to mere dialectal differences.

Comment: @vectory Why is it unlikely? By the same argument, the word "this" itself is unlikely to appear in any writing—and yet, it does all the time. The argument is nonsense. People (or at least literate people) have no problem abstracting deixis in this way. Also, "this" isn't a preposition.

Comment: @vectory  As for what was used before a word was coined: same as always, same a today, people use less-direct, multiple-word locutions for things they don't have a word for. If I want to talk about the day after today, I use the word "tomorrow". If I want to talk about the day after that—well, that hasn't been important enough often enough for English to invent a word for it, so I have to say "in two days" or "two days hence" or "the day after tomorrow" or various other options to express it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88288/discussion-between-vectory-and-abarnert).

Comment: (I assumed you were talking about Ancient Greek -- thanks for the clarification.)

Comment: @TKR I think didn't make it clear enough—and I may have actually been confused by my source. At any rate, I've removed the Greek stuff from my answer, and I think it's better without it, so thanks for bringing it up.